# What is the point of Multithreading if you have to wait for each thread to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to multithreading but in every tutorial that I have found it says to use the join method so that you wait for each thread to finish before doing the next one. What is the point of multithreading if each thread executes one at a time?

Comment: I think either the tutorial is bad or you are misunderstanding what they are saying. With that said there are reasons to use join. Also you are correct in that if you start a thread then immediately join you don't get the benefit of multiple threads.

Comment: If you are preparing dinner for 4 guests and you have 4 cooks. Each cook prepares a dish for each guest. You'll wait for the slower cook before serving dinner. That's all what join does i.e. sync the threads.

Comment: So is join optional then for when you need a specific thread to finish before another specific thread runs, but you can also have them running at the same time?

Comment: They (books) show you how to wait for thread to finish. But you can start 10 threads and then wait some of them or all to finish. It depends on the real work to do whether 2+ tasks can run in the same time. And in most cases (apps) second thread is necessary mainly for the user interface.

Comment: @GaryFisher -- no, `join()` is not optional. (well, formally, if you `detach()` a thread, you don't have to `join()` it, but creating a detached thread is a **design** decision, not a workaround for not wanting to call `join()`).

Comment: @PeteBecker So let me see if I understand this correctly. When I create a new thread I _must_ call `join()` on it in the thread that it was created in(I assume this is to prevent threads from going out of scope and/or the program ending with threads still running). However, I _can_  create multiple threads(inside of one thread, probably the main thread) and all of those threads can run simultaneously. Is this correct?

Comment: @GaryFisher -- sooner or later someone with access to the `std::thread` object has to `join()` it.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that you can start 4 threads, and then join 4 threads. This works well when each thread can do a quarter of the work.

If your problem is sequential in nature, you're indeed right that threads do not help. This is a well-known restriction; it's called [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) and was observed already back in 1967.

Comment: It might be important to note that "start 4 threads, and then join 4 threads" is very different from "start one thread and join it, 4 times"

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have 1.000.000 datasets you need to access and modifiy.
If you have a single threaded application, you need to wait to finish 1.000.000 datasets.

With multithreading you can split the work and each thread executes **simultaneously**.
If you have 1.000.000 datasets and 4 threads, in the very best case you only need to wait as long **as if** you had 250.000 datasets.

If you have no dependencies between executions and your workload is heavy, you should consider using multithreading.